# Construct the Green's function for the following boundary value problem and use it to find the solution $y''-y'=t^2$

Tags: adjoint-operators, greens-function

> Construct the Green's function for the following boundary value problem and use it to find the solution $$y''-y'=t^2,\quad y(0)=0,\: y(1)=0$$

I know that,

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\langle L u, G\rangle=\langle f, G\rangle \\
&\left\langle u, L^{\dagger} G\right\rangle=\langle f, G\rangle \\
&\langle u, \delta(x-\xi)\rangle=\langle f, G\rangle \\
&u(\xi)=\langle f, G\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$
The Green's Function Solution
$$
u(x)=\int_{0}^{l} f(\xi) G(\xi, x) d \xi
$$

---

Okay, the linear operator $L=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-\frac{d}{dx}$ with boundary conditions $y(0)=0,\: y(1)=0$. I get the adjoint operator with Green function $L^{\dagger}G=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}G+\frac{d}{dx}G=\delta(x-\xi)  \quad G(0)=0,\: G(1)=0$ where the bondary conditions come from Conjunct or Bilinear Concomitant (set to zero). But I am facing issue to solve the $L^{\dagger}G=\delta(x-\xi)$.

Comment: Should your second condition be $y'(1) $ rather than $ y(1)$? Or on $y(0)$, by your conditions it appears you have a double valued function.

Comment: No. That's the problem. @Luthier

Comment: For seek of completeness, I get the idea of the method from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqfYSNsrnhI) video.