# What is a bilinear concomitant (or conjunt) with regards to linear differential operators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hessian-matrix, eigenfunctions, self-adjoint-operators

**Context**

I am studying self-adjoint eigenfunction problems using [1]. I am working through Example 1 on page 54 in [1].

**Example 1 (page 54 in [1])**

Suppose we have the linear differential operator
$$ L[y] = \sum_{s = 1}^2\frac{d^s}{dx^s}\left(r_s(x)\frac{d^sy}{dx^s}\right).$$
Because of the form of the operator, I know that $L[\cdot]$ is formally self adjoint.

Let, $u(x)$ be a solution to the system
$$L[u] = 0,$$
and let $v(x)$ be a solution to the adjoint system
$$L^*[v] = 0.$$

I want to determine the bilinear concomitant, $J(u,v)$.

*Question 1*

What is the definition of a bilinear concomitant?

I have found no answer in wikipedia.org,  encyclopediaofmath.org, or CRC Math Encyclopedia. A related question [2], seems to indicate that a bilinear concomitant is also known as a *conjunct*. A search of wikipedia, encyclopediaofmath, and CRC again come up empty handed for *conjunct*. A related question [4], has a pdf link to [5]. In [5], the term *bilinear concomitant* is used several times, but I have seen no definition for it.

*Question 2*

In [1], Zwillinger states that

> "$J(u,v)$ is called the bilinear concomitant and is defined by
> \begin{equation}
> J(v,w) = \sum_{m=1}^{n} \,\, \sum_{j+k=m-1}  (-1)^k \left(\frac{d^k}{dt^k}\left(p_m\,u\right)\right)\left(\frac{d^jv}{dt^j} \right)  ."
> \end{equation}

This has the feeling of some type of determinant of a Hessian, which is what appeared in the entry for comitant in [3].

I am not even sure how to interpret Zwillinger's definition, I think it may be either
\begin{equation}
J(v,w) = \sum_{m=1}^{n} \,\, \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}  (-1)^k \left(\frac{d^{(k)}}{dt^{(k)}}\left(p_m\,u\right)\right)\left(\frac{d^{(m-1-k)}v}{dt^{(m-1-k)}} \right),
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
J(v,w) = \sum_{m=1}^{n} \,\, \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}  (-1)^k \left(\frac{d^{(k)}}{dt^{(k)}}\left(p_m\,u\right)\right)\left(\frac{d^{(m-1-k)}v}{dt^{(m-1-k)}} \right)  
\end{equation}

Which, if any, of these two interpretations is the correct reading of Zwillinger's definition for bilinear concomitant?

**References**

[1] Zwillinger, "Handbook on Differential Equations," Academic Press, Inc. 1989, 1st Edition.

[2] [Construct the Green's function for the following boundary value problem and use it to find the solution $y''-y'=t^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375303/construct-the-greens-function-for-the-following-boundary-value-problem-and-use)

[3] https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Comitant

[4] [When do boundary conditions specify a unique solution to ODEs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387989/when-do-boundary-conditions-specify-a-unique-solution-to-odes/2388097#2388097)

[5] [http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~lebovitz/Eodesbook/bv.pdf](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Elebovitz/Eodesbook/bv.pdf)

Comment: Solving for the adjoint of a formally self-adjoint operator will consist of performing integration by parts a number of times.  Each instance of integration by parts will produce one non-integral term and one integral term, and the end result will be that one of the terms contains as many integrals as you started with, where the integrand is $L[v]$.  All of the other terms picked up by integration by parts collectively form the conjunct or bilinear concomitant.  Here is an excellent explanation of the whole process:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aG5tFA8GJ78

Comment: @user10478, Great video! Out of curiosity, do you have a book that on differential equations that you would recommend?

Comment: The only book I have studied is Differential Equations With Boundary Value Problems by Polking Boggess and Arnold, but it does not cover this material.  It is an introductory level book perhaps 75% on ODEs and 25% on PDEs, and I just supplemented PDE topics it didn't cover with Youtube lectures.